# Why passing ref struct to methods actually passes a copy of a ref struct?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-9.0

When I'm trying to pass a ref struct that looks like, say

```
public ref struct BufferWriter
{
    readonly Buffer* _pb;
    public int WrittenBytes;
    //...
    public bool Append(ReadOnlySpan<byte> buffer)
    {
        //...
        WrittenBytes += buffer.Length;
        //...
    }
    
}
```

to a method (`Write100U8Chars(BufferWriter, Object)` in the following example), a struct is not actually passed by a reference, but by the value:

```
protected override bool Serialize(object obj)
{
    //...
    fixed (Buffer* pb = &doc_body)
    {
        using (BufferWriter writer = new BufferWriter(pb))
        {
            writer.Append("UTF8 str"U8);
            // pb->Bytes is now 8
            // writer.WrittenBytes is now also 8
            Write100U8Chars(writer, obj);
            // pb->Bytes is now 108
            // But writer.WrittenBytes is still 8!
        }
    }
    //...
}

// A method that always calls BufferWriter.Append passing 100 UTF-8 chars (aka bytes) 
protected abstract bool Write100U8Chars(BufferWriter writer, object obj);
```

Because of the `using` block being kind of read-only context which, as I supposed, enforces making "defensive copies", I've attempted to remove the `using` block/directive:

```
fixed (Buffer* pb = &doc_body)
{
    BufferWriter writer = new BufferWriter(pb)
    writer.Append("UTF8 str"U8);
    // writer.WrittenBytes is now 8
    Write100U8Chars(writer, obj);
    // No use of removing using: writer.WrittenBytes is still 8
}
```

Making `BufferWriter` a `ref readonly struct` makes no difference.

Passing a `writer` local to a method `Write100U8Chars(BufferWriter, Object)` with `in` parameter still makes no difference.

How can I make a `ref struct` be passed into abstract method by reference and not by value like it is the case with ordinary non-ref structs?

Comment: A ref struct behaves exactly like a regular struct.  It is still a value type so gets passed by value in a method call.  Its only use is to generate compile errors, happens when the struct might end up on the GC heap or otherwise require a reference and thus get less efficient.  These syntax changes were made to make C# behave more like C++, but the potential improvements are quite modest and certainly didn't make C# any easier to use.  Only use them when a profiler tells you it might be worth the effort.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks! Seems like I've misunderstood what does `ref` actually mean and I've really never tried using ref structs in such way.

Comment: Any particular reason you are using fixed pointers anyway? You could just use a `Span` by itself

Comment: @Charlieface generally you're right. However, this approach encapsulates `Buffer` by providing APIs for resizing, generally it behaves just like `MemoryStream`, but after the `BufferWriter` disposal, it should perform resizing of the buffer thus we need to keep the fixed pointer to a `Buffer` object. Anyway it's just an internal logic of the library. Btw, if it were C# 11, a `Buffer` could've just been a ref field. But the code is written both for .NET 7.0 and .NET Standard 2.1, so a pointers will do the job for both of frameworks.

Comment: This is an approach the library uses for generating a batch of possibly huge files. Buffer is created by malloc, which does not zero out memory unlike calloc, allocating a managed buffer or using any wrappers, such as `MemoryStream`. The allocated memory is filled with random leftover data and we can safely write into it, but the rest of the unused garbage should be truncated away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
protected abstract bool Write100U8Chars(BufferWriter writer, object obj);
```

This call is passing `writer` by value. If you want to pass it by reference, it should be:

```
protected abstract bool Write100U8Chars(ref BufferWriter writer, object obj);
```

As far as I understand it, the `ref` in the struct declaration is used to define how the value type can be allocated (only stack) but it will still behave as a regular struct and get passed by value by default.

Comment: This answer needs to address how `public ref struct BufferWriter` doesn't affect what happens with a `ref` parameter.

Comment: I see `writer.WrittenBytes` but where is `writer.bytes`?

Comment: That would be `writer._pb->Bytes` and would be inaccessible with that syntax (`_pb` is private).

Comment: @InBetween `pb` is of type `Buffer*`, whereas `writer` is of type `BufferWriter`

Comment: Yes. I've been thinking `ref struct` literally means a "stack `struct` pointer", but actually, it is a value of the `struct` itself.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of `ref struct` is to allow the struct to use types that can only ever be permitted to exist on the stack. The typical example is `Span<T>`, but C# 11 also allow ref fields. The main point is that memory safety can be violated if the struct is stored on the heap.

As far as I can tell, your struct does not need this, since a pointer should be possible to use in a regular struct. This does potentially violate memory safety, but pointers need unsafe code anyway, so memory safety is out the window already.

If you want to pass a reference to a struct you need to declare that in the method, i.e. `void MyMethod(ref BufferWriter)`

Comment: Thanks. I'll just point out that the `BufferWriter` is a `ref struct` because it should not exist after method that consumed it, returns.

Comment: @D-Kay I'm not sure I understand your reasoning. No struct exist after the method that created it returns, unless copied. Sure, `ref struct` prevents it from being copied to the heap, and that might be useful. But it could still 'escape' if it was returned, sure, that would be stupid, but 'unsafe' is deliberately turning of the protections against stupid mistakes.

Comment: There is no stack/heap restriction. There is purely a restriction on placing it in fields, which prevents them escaping the function call. Local variables being stored on the native stack is not necessarily true: they could in theory be stored on a heap somewhere, equally classes could be placed on the stack. In other words: the no-field restriction in practice becomes a no-heap restriction on most builds of .NET, but that distinction is not actually relevant.

Comment: @Charlieface Sure, But I'm using the terminology from the [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/ref-struct): "Instances of a ref struct type are allocated on the stack and can't escape to the managed heap.". If "managed heap" is is good enough for the docs it is good enough for me. Even if I did assume the "managed" part to be implied.

Comment: @JonasH yes, you're right, that's just to protect from `BufferWriter` being copied to a field of a managed-heap-allocated object. That is done because if `Buffer` is still in use in the caller, modifying `Buffer` by calling `BufferWriter.Append` methods in callee object after the method returns can be damaging to `Buffer`.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit old, but I just found this, and recent about the synergy between `readonly` and `in`. So even value types run into defensive copies, even ref structs even though they may only exist on the stack. Furthermore, even **`readonly`** value types may be defensively copied. In.. whichever version, 8 or 9, maybe lower, I can't remember, you can actually use `readonly` synergistically with `in` keyword in your method declaration in order to prevent this defensive copy, to some extent. I can't claim to know all the heuristics it uses to decide whether or not this happens, but it does increase the chances of defensive copies of readonly value types not being made. It may help, if you can figure out an architecture in which to utilize it.

If you check out the Span, at least from inside VS, it looks like:

```
public readonly ref struct Span<T>
```

So if you've got say..

```
Span<T> = T[].AsSpan()
```

and then a function..

```
internal void HandleSpan(in Span<T> span) {}
```

You **may** be able to get around this defensive copying.